# Can I access /dev/urandom with open_basedir in effect?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpass

I want to use phpass-0.3 in Codeigniter, but I get the following error due to `open_basedir`:

> A PHP Error was encountered    
>  Severity: Warning    
>   Message: is_readable() [function.is-readable]: open_basedir
>   restriction in effect. File(/dev/urandom) is not within the allowed
>   path(s): (/home/phginep:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp)
>   Filename: phpass-0.3/PasswordHash.php  
>    Line Number: 51

Following code:

```
function get_random_bytes($count)
{
    $output = '';
    if (is_readable('/dev/urandom') &&    //Line Number: 51
        ($fh = @fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb'))) {
        $output = fread($fh, $count);
        fclose($fh);
    }

    if (strlen($output) < $count) {
        $output = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 16) {
            $this->random_state =
                md5(microtime() . $this->random_state);
            $output .=
                pack('H*', md5($this->random_state));
        }
        $output = substr($output, 0, $count);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Is there anything I can do to get around this?

Answer (score 16):

You have some options here:

1 - Download a dump from a true RNG ([this one](http://www.random.org/files/) offers dumps from one based on radioactive decay) and use that, just be sure that you don't keep reading the same nn bytes. Kind of clunky, but an option.

2 - Have PHP execute something that reads from `/dev/urandom` on its behalf (UGLY)

3 - Fall back on `mt_rand()` (Also ugly, but I've seen this done):

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < $count / 8; $i++) {
   $output .= dechex(mt_rand(0, 0x7fffffff));
 }
```

All options are clunky and ugly, unfortunately. The best thing to do would be sure that you don't have to deal with `open_basedir`. Still, this particular annoyance could be worked around.

**Finally - not likely to fly with your host, but perhaps worth a try:**

You can ask your host to provide `urandom` in your home directory so you can read it. Tell them you need to access urandom to generate random numbers so you can provide better security for your users, then ask them to run:

```
mknod urandom c 1 9
```

In your home directory. I just tried it on my own server, it works (but root needs to do it for you). There is *no* practical reason to keep you from using the system's pseudo random number generator, which you could do otherwise with anything other than PHP. This is actually the easiest way for them to let you have access to `urandom` because it requires no exceptions in the PHP or vhost configuration for you.

Disallowing access to `/dev/random` is a reasonable thing to do, since `/dev/random` must be replenished by available (new) system entropy and might cause important things to block on read if exhausted which could happen often on low traffic servers. However, `/dev/urandom` is guaranteed to never block since it just reuses the internal entropy pool once exhausted, which is why it's a lesser quality source.

**Note**

I'm not saying the *idea* of `open_basedir` is a bad one, but it breaks *good* code too. A classic `chroot` is much better, but harder, which is why you run into `open_basedir` much more than you do a real chroot. At the minimum, any program should be able to access the `null`, `zero` and `urandom` devices on a server.

Comment: for the people reading in 2020; you can use [random_bytes()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php)

Answer (score 6):

phpass is trying to access `/dev/urandom`, which is not allowed in your `php.ini`
To resolve this issue, you must suppress the warning. To do so, just add `@` before `is_readable`, like this :

```
...
@is_readable('/dev/urandom')
...
```

Comment: Actually you are hiding the issue more than solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're on shared hosting hosting and they've configured PHP to only allow you to access files and directories within your account (which makes sense). If this is the case there isn't much you can do as shared hosting will not allow change to allow you to access that resource. If you have a dedicated server or VPS you can alter your PHP configuration (php.ini) to allow access to that resource.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /nginx/chroot/
touch random
touch urandom
mount --bind /dev/random /nginx/chroot/dev/random
mount --bind /dev/urandom /nginx/chroot/dev/urandom
```

and my phpmailer has now working in nginx chroot centos 7

php nginx RAND_BYTES stream_socket_enable_crypto
php nginx stream_socket_enable_crypto
Uncaught Exception: Cannot open source device
php nginx RAND_BYTES stream_socket_enable_crypto
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL